# Using SQLFilter while receiving message Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Currently I am using below code:

```
MessagingFactory mf = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(RuntimeConfig.ConnectionStrings.PrimaryAzureSb);
MessageReceiver mr = mf.CreateMessageReceiver(string.Format("{0}/subscriptions/{1}", topicName, subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock));
```

to receive message from the topic.

But i need to filter message while receiving and so I have tried adding SQLFilter but i could not achieve.

Is there any ways to add SQLFilter for Topics and Subscription which are already exist.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you expecting to use SQL filter when receiving messages from a subscription? In other words, you would like to receive messages from a subscription matching a particular SQL filter?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes .. i need to use SQLFilter

Comment: Note about the library you're using: if you're just starting to use Azure Service Bus, please use the new client [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/).

Answer (score 0):

To filter messages between different Subscriptions under a Topic, you can create Rules for Topic Subscriptions.

While defining the Rule, provide the SQL filter expression for the Rule.

The messages with the required custom properties and system properties, which satisfies the expression in the Rule will only get into the Subscription.

Please refer here for [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters)